# How do I install GDI+ version 1.1 on Windows XP?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, windows-xp

Has anyone done this successfully? As I understand, GDI+ 1.1 only ships with Vista. I'm trying to get my hands on the different Effects classes.

I'm using C++ VS2008 (VC9)

Comment: I'm guessing Microsoft would rather you just upgrade your version of Windows.

Comment: Please do edit my question when it comes to details, bad grammar or spelling errors. But please dont edit out my name or my greeting to anyone if I so choose to add to my question. It's just plain rude.

Comment: So what they are saying is that I should only use vista as a developer and that I should only develop for vista. Oh well darn :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GDI+ 1.1 is not redistributable according to EULA of Windows Vista.

Answer (score 1):

There is a version of GDI+ 1.1 in Office 2003 that does not work with the interfaces provided by Vista SDK. I am not sure if you can guess out the signatures of the flat APIs or not.

[there was strategic decision made to not redistribute GDI+ 1.1](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.gdi/browse_frm/thread/904880ea5bb3a022/3b0a2120c3b7c8?hl=en&ie=UTF-8&q=#003b0a2120c3b7c8)