# How to force a dll to load from current directory

Tags: delphi

I have copied a newer version of `GdiPlus.dll` to my projects directory. 
However windows always loads it form

> "C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.Windows.GdiPlus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.0.6002.23084_x-ww_f3f35550\GdiPlus.dll"

I'm on XP.

Comment: The [`search order`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx) picks a library from your project's binary folder first, so put that library to your exe and it should be loaded from there.

Comment: @TLama, It is there, in my project directory with my EXE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To exert complete control over DLL loading, pass the full path of the DLL to `LoadLibrary`.

This is viable if you use runtime linking. For load time linking you are reliant on the DLL search order. The first thing searched is the directory from where the exe loaded. That said, it is plausible that for an OS component like GDI+ it is plausible that the system will use the SxS DLL no matter what.

Your question title says "current directory" but you never want to rely on the value of the current directory when linking DLLs. The current directory's value is unpredictable.

Finally, GDI+ is a system component and I think it doubtful that providing your own GDI+ DLL is a wise move. It is quite possibly illegal too since [redistribution of GDI+ is not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724332/how-do-i-install-gdi-version-1-1-on-windows-xp). Perhaps you are choosing the wrong solution to your problem.

Comment: GDI+ is statically linked to the exe. there is no `LoadLibrary`. I have tried to `LoadLibrary(path_to_my_dll)` in the initialization section, but that just load 2 gdiplus dlls. regarding your "Finally" I have seen a lot of programs distributed with "gdiplus.dll". you might be right about choosing this solution, but I only want to test  something for now. i.e. why same GDI+ function works ok on Vista but not on XP.

Comment: And sorry, I meant current project directory containing my EXE.

Comment: It is against the EULA to redistribute a Vista or later GDI+ DLL to XP. I think you'll need to find a different way around your problem.

Comment: "That said, it is plausible that for an OS component like GDI+ it is plausible that the system will use the SxS DLL no matter what." It seems this is the case. can you confirm that please? I manually changed `const WINGDIPDLL = 'D:\Projects\Foo\GdiPlus.dll';` and now it loads the correct DLL (I will undo this finally).

Comment: I think it's highly likely that SxS wins every time. Don't have XP here.

Comment: I guess, you are trying to use the bitmap effect functions. They are part of the GDI+ 1.1 extensions. Unfortunately, WinXP doesn't ship with GDI+ 1.1. Its available on Windows Vista and higher, but if I remember, there was a certain Microsoft Office 2003 version (Plus, extended or something), providing it too.

Comment: @PeterKostov, I simply need to load an icon with GDI+ and preserve it's alpha channel which works fine on Vista but not on XP. http://stackoverflow.com/q/26486504/3906993

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, What I meant by "can you confirm that" was, is it somewhere documented that the system might choose to load a specific dll regardless of Search Order and the fact that GdiPlus.dll is not listed in KnownDLLs?: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I expect that it is documented, but I have never been able to understand SxS or its documentation. Sorry.

Comment: Are you looking for more help here?

Comment: I could accept this answer if that's what you mean. but your answer still not conclusive IMHO. if SxS is "winning" a DLL which is not listed in KnownDLLs, I want to know why it does. wouldn't you?

Comment: Well, the question asks how to force the loading of a specific version of a DLL. I think the paragraph deals with that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this declaration to set the directory of `dll` to a defined path.

```
function SetDllDirectory(lpPathName:PWideChar): Bool; stdcall; external 'kernel32.dll' name 'SetDllDirectoryW';
```

remember to change the path after working with your `dll`.

Comment: This function does not do what you seem to claim it does. It is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686203.aspx